# Why should Always use immutable collection interfaces to declare collections which are not mutated in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, immutability

I'm reading Kotlin docs. At Immutability sector, they comment below. I wonder why should we do that? When I tried the example code, it acts the same.

> **Immutability**
>
> Prefer using immutable data to mutable. Always declare local variables
>   and properties as val rather than var if they are not modified after
>   initialization.
>
> Always use immutable collection interfaces ( Collection , List , Set ,
>   Map ) to declare collections which are not mutated. When using factory
>   functions to create collection instances, always use functions that
>   return immutable collection types when possible:
>
> ```
> // Bad: use of mutable collection type for value which will not be mutated
> fun validateValue(actualValue: String, allowedValues: HashSet<String>) { ... }
> // Good: immutable collection type used instead
> fun validateValue(actualValue: String, allowedValues: Set<String>) { ... }
> // Bad: arrayListOf() returns ArrayList<T>, which is a mutable collection type
> val allowedValues = arrayListOf("a", "b", "c")
> // Good: listOf() returns List<T>
> val allowedValues = listOf("a", "b", "c")
> ```

Updated: For anyone who voted me down. I read this book, tried the example and tried to search before writing this question. So I don't have enough experience to explain or comprehend the paragraph above. Let consider what you contribute to this community. If I do wrong, let me know. Don't click only one button.

Comment: Why do you want to use mutable if you are not planning on changing the data structure? If anything having the data structure immutable will prevent you or others from changing it by accident.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to use mutable. Maybe I don't understand `ArrayList<T>` and `List<T>` in Kotlin. In Java, `List<T>` just be an `Interface`. Therefore, I can't understand that suggests.

Comment: `List<T>` is an interface in Kotlin as well.

Comment: Oh, so this problem stands for the difference between `arrayListOf` and `listOf `. Let me read the API Docs again. Thank u for your help.

Comment: I think you should compare `MutableList<T>` and `List<T>`. Both are interfaces, whereas `ArrayList<T>` is a concrete class from Java. `ArrayList<T>` implements `MutableList<T>` in Kotlin. `MutableList<T>` extends `List<T>`, adding mutability functionalities which are not in `List<T>` originally.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I read the `listOf ` docs. The `listOf ` method returns a list object that can't add any new item. That's something I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the suggestion of Mr.@Akavall and Mr.@Naetmul. I read the `listOf` method's docs again. The problem has I missed that the `listOf` method returns a list object that can't add any new item.

> I think you should compare MutableList and List. Both are
>   interfaces, whereas ArrayList is a concrete class from Java.
>   ArrayList implements MutableList in Kotlin. MutableList
>   extends List, adding mutability functionalities which are not in
>   List originally.